# Wrong output in Diffk II Problem in Leetcode using set. Why is set being used to solve this problem?

Tags: c++, set

The Diffk II Problem is :
Given an array A of integers and another non negative integer k, find if there exists 2 indices i and j such that A[i] - A[j] = k, i != j

The code I found online is :

```
if (a.size() < 2 || k < 0) return 0;
    set<int> s;
    //for(int el : a)
      //  s.insert(el);
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        int diff1 = a[i]-k;
        int diff2 = k+a[i];
        if(s.find(diff1)!=s.end())
            return 1;
        if(s.find(diff2)!=s.end())
            return 1;
         s.insert(a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

Why am not getting the correct output if uncomment the 2 lines in the beginning and comment the insert statement inside the for loop ?
And why are we using a set? When we use a set, we ignore the duplicates present in the vector.
Can't we use a map? So that we do not lose any element in case the input vector contains duplicate values?

Comment: What is the need to populate the set inside the for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncomment the 2 lines

```
    //for(int el : a)
      //  s.insert(el);
```

It means all elements will be added at the beginning.

`k` is non negative, so it may become zero.

Therefore, the function will give ignore the `i != j` condition and give false-positive when `k` is zero (searching for `A[i] = A[j]`).

When inerting inside the loop, the indice of elements in `s` are granteed to be less than `i`.
That is because the `i != j` condition won't ignored in this case.
Assuming that, you don't have to use the indice otherwise, so using `map` to hold indice is not required.